# How to use SELF-DISCOVER prompting framework with OpenAI GPT-4 model?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-4

I have read this blog - [# Revolutionizing Language Model Reasoning: Google’s SELF-DISCOVER Prompting Framework](https://medium.com/@aitoolsfinder/revolutionizing-language-model-reasoning-googles-self-discover-prompting-framework-6f44f5be41d1)

The content is like the following:

In recent years, large language models (LLMs) have shown remarkable promise in a variety of applications, from language translation to chatbots. However, one major challenge in working with LLMs is their limited reasoning capabilities, which can hinder their ability to solve complex problems and understand human-like language.

To address this challenge, researchers from Google DeepMind and the University of Southern California have developed a new approach called the SELF-DISCOVER prompting framework. This framework promises to significantly enhance the reasoning abilities of LLMs, potentially revolutionizing the performance of leading models such as OpenAIs GPT-4 and Googles PaLM 2.

[image]

After reading this blog, I felt the urge to try self-discover framework with gpt-4.

How to use it? And How to implement in python?